# Resetting angular dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dropdown that I can't reset. When I click "clear" I expect the dropdown to reset, however, it stay on the last selection.

I successfully reset the other dropdown in the same way, but I can't reset the first dropdown. I'm new to angular and would appreciate any help.

```
<div class="db-dropdown">
    <label for="dbdropdown">Site selection:</label>
    <select required class="dbdropdown" name="dbdropdown" id="dbdropdown" [(ngModel)]="selectedLabel" (change)="onSelect(selectedLabel)" [disabled]="isRunning">
        <option value='Please select DB'>Please select DB</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.label">{{option.label}}</option>
    </select>

    <div *ngIf="selectedValues && selectedValues.length">
        <app-connectionCode-dropdown></app-connectionCode-dropdown>
    </div>
</div>
```

**this is my ngOnInit in dropdown.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedLabel = this.dataService.selectedLabelDBSelection;
    this.DBDropdownService.getOptions().subscribe(options => {
      this.options = options;
    });
    this.dataService.isRunning$.subscribe(isRunning => this.isRunning = isRunning)
  }
```

**and the resetting method on buttons.ts:**

```
resetSelects() {
    console.log('resetting selects');
    this.dataService.setRunClick(false);
    this.dataService.setSelectedValueDb('Please select DB');
    this.dataService.setSelectedLabelDBSelection('Please select DB');
    console.log('selectedLabelDBSelection:', this.dataService.selectedLabelDBSelection);
    this.dataService.setSelectedValue('');
    this.dataService.setSelectedProcedure('');
    this.dataService.clearContents.next(true);
    this.dataService.setIsRunning(false);
  }
```

**and the relevant method on the service:**

```
setSelectedLabelDBSelection(value: string){
    this.selectedLabelDBSelection = value;
  }
selectedLabelDBSelection: string;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the issue is how you resetting the **selectedLabelDBSelection** value.

In your **resetSelects()** method, you are setting the selectedLabelDBSelection value to "Please select DB" using the setSelectedLabelDBSelection method, but the dropdown value is bound to the ngModel variable **selectedLabel**.

Try setting the **selectedLabel** variable to "Please select DB" in your **resetSelects()** method, like this:

```
this.selectedLabel = 'Please select DB';
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. the setSelectedLabelDBSelection is a method in my service. that reset the variable selectedLabelDBSelection on the service and in turn on the dropdown.component  on ngOnInit: this.selectedLabel = this.dataService.selectedLabelDBSelection;